# Performance of where statement in SQL as opposed to filter on dataset

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

please flog me if I haven't searched thoroughly enough.....

I am wondering what would be better for performance:

Collect, aggregate and sort my data using SQL (WHERE, Group by, Order By statements in dataset)
or
just collect the 'naked' data and group, sort and filter in the report. (Filters on dataset, parameters and aggregating in the report)

Would using stored procedures be beneficial to performance?

Greetings,

Henro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, SSRS is a tool to display results, it is optimized to do that, and though it can perform aggregations and filters and a lot more things, it doesn't means that its his primary goal, so its not optimized to do that. When you perform the aggregations, filters and data manipulation on the dataset, you are using the database engine for that, something that its optimized to do that, so you are most likely get better performance this way. As for stored procedures or plain SQL, there is no inherent performance benefits in either of one (I prefer plain SQL only because it gives me more flexibility).

Comment: When I need datasets to populate  for example parameters, I would 1. create a new dataset which links to that shared dataset but 2. with non-appropriate fields removed. That way, I would be sure that all reports use the same set of data but would allow for a lot of flexibility in creating reports with different groupings.  Unfortunately, experience tells us that, if we use embedded datasets which are grouped, sorted and filtered and all, and a change is needed, we have to check all the datasets and make sure that change is reflected everywhere. Apart from being tedious, it is very error-prone.

Comment: But I understand from your answer that that will have impact on performance. How would you go about when you need different reports on the same set of data?

Comment: @Henrov - You asked about the performance of each approach. Now, as always, if you want to gain flexibility, you have to pay with something else, in this case is performance. The best performance will be less flexible and the most flexible will have an impact on performance. As to wich one would I choose, it depends if the report needs to be really fast or not, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of performance, SQL Server is optimized for that sort of thing;

Under certain circumstances, a stored procedure can significantly increase performance as it precompiles the query plan... in this case, unless the report is being called quite often, I don't know if you'll notice the difference.  I do prefer to keep my SQL out of the report, though.